# Use ASP.NET 4 feature "ClientIDMode" in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, client

I have seen a great feature of ASP.NET 4, the property of server controls "ClientIDMode". Can I use this feature in ASP.NET 3.5 in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use this feature in ASP.NET 3.5 in any way?

No, you can't. That's an ASP.NET 4 feature. Time to upgrade?