# How to stop asp.net from auto generating ids?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a asp.net page that has several form elements.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myID" runat="server"/>
```

I am running these at the server level because I need to assign values to them.

The Asp.net engine is auto assigning ids and names, overriding my specified ID.

For purposes of my application I have to have specific IDs on these fields. Since this is an older version of .Net <4 I can not use the ClientIDMode=Static value.

Is there anyway that I can force static IDs?

Comment: No; that feature is new to ASP.Net 4.0.

Comment: "For purposes of my application I have to have specific IDs" can you explain this requirement a little more?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use ASP.NET 4 feature "ClientIDMode" in ASP.NET 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060905/use-asp-net-4-feature-clientidmode-in-asp-net-3-5)

Comment: I agree with @MikeSmithDev.  If you explain what your intent is, maybe we can help you solve the underlying problem (or work around it).  As the question stands, it is a duplicate.

Comment: You could populate your html controls via ajax and then get the values on postback with Request.Form["name-attribute"]

Comment: It won't rewrite a Name attribute, would that be possible?

Comment: The third party page that this is posted to requires very specific naming.

Comment: The Name attribute seems to be overwritten at some level also.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to assign static values is new to .net version 4.0 but you can get the value assigned to controls and pass that to other bits of JavaScript.

Create your own hidden controls with the `IDs` and `Names` that you want. Use some simple JavaScript on your form submission to copy values from the server side controls to your controls.

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <asp:TextBox ID=MyTextBox" runat="server" />
    <input type="hidden" id="MyFixedID" name="MyFixedName" />
    <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Go!" />
</form>

function fred() {
    $("#<%=MyButton.ClientID %>").Click(function() {
        $("#MyFixedID").val($("#<%=MyTextBox.ClientID %>").val());
        $("#MyForm").submit()
    });
}
```

I have also used `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` or `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` to emit JavaScript and pass the server side `Control.ClientID` as a parameter to a function defined within a `<script>` block.

Comment: For some reason, it made me laugh that you named that arbitrary JavaScript function "fred".

Comment: A long standing naming convention based on a mentor 20 years ago. Anything named `"fred"` (file, directory, code etc) was transient and could be deleted at will if space was needed. I rarely let my use of "fred" spill out onto SO. No intention of offending the Freds of this world.

Comment: It'd not a matter of passing the values to a javascript or jquery function. That's pretty straight forward. The form itself gets posted to a third party page that requires explicit naming.